# How to Spawn Shape Keys as Objects from One Object?

Tags: shape-keys

i swear, this used to be a thing.  i was doing it a lot last year.

i have an object with a dozen shape keys.  because reasons (blender is a butt), i need to spawn duplicates of this object, with each shape key applied as the new basis.

i can't seem to find where/how to do it in 3.60.  is it an addon?  is it from 2.79??

i have 'corrective shape keys' and 'transfer shape keys' addons active.

Comment: if you mean that a shapekey needs to be the new basis, then simply delete all the shapekey except the one you're talking about? You can also move the shapekey to top, it will replace the basis